# How to validate the excel sheet value so that only correct data type value insert in to mysql database through php

Tags: php

I want to actually import the .csv file to a database, my problem is that when I validate the data of excel sheet, only actual data should get inserted to the database. If one of the row does not match with the actual data type then it should show the message `this rows can not be insert in to database` using only php.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i want to import the excel file and my problem is that i have many tables in report, actually i am making a report there are some column for basic user information in 1 table and in other company work and so on ..

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php sometimes manuals are good. :)